# Did anyone besides Vishnu or Krishna use a Chakra as a weapon?

Tags: sudarsana

Sudarshana Chakra is Vishnu's weapon. Is Chakra a generic weapon used by others besides Vishnu ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goddess Chandika also used this weapon. Various deities offered her with various weapons of their choices before the fight against the Mahisasura.

All the references here are from the Devi Bhagavata Purana (DB).

> Visnu then created another thousand spoked discus (Chakram) from His
>   own Chakra, capable to take off the head of any Asura, and offered it
>   to Her. S’ankara created another excellent Tris'ûla from his own
>   Trident, terrible and demon-killing, and offered it to the Devî.
>   Varuna created another bright conch from his own conch and offered it
>   gladly to the Devî. Fire offered Her a weapon named S'ataghni which
>   kills violently the demons, as if that is another god of death. Maruta
>   (wind), the chief of the gods, offered Her a wonderful bow and arrow
>   case filled with arrows
>
> **DB Book 5; Chapter 9**

> Thus Bhagavatî Mahisamardinî was born of the Tejas (fiery substances)
>   of the Devas. Next S’iva gave Her the S’ûla (weapon spear); Visnu gave
>   Sudars'ana (Chakra); Varuna gave the conchshell; Fire gave S'akti
>   (weapon); Vâyu gave Her bows and arrows; Indra gave Her thunder bolt
>   and the bell of the elephant Airâvata; Yama gave Her the Destruction
>   Staff (Kâla Danda); Brâmâ gave Her the Rudrâksa, rosary and Kamandalu;
>   the Sun gave Her, in every pore the wonderful rays; the Time (Kâla)
>   gave Her sharp axe and shield; the oceans gave Her the beautiful
>   necklace and new clothes (two in number); Vis'vakarmâ gladly gave Her
>   the crown, ear-rings, kataka, Angada, Chandrârdha, tinklets; and the
>   Himâlayâs gave Her the Lion as Her Vehicle and various gems and jewels
>
> **DB 10.12**

The demon called Andhaka also had a Chakra-like weapon of his own which was like the Sudrashana in might.

> 24-39. The Dânava Mahisa struck Garuda, the conveyance of Hari, with
>   his club; Garuda, being very much distressed with the blow, sat down,
>   gasping. Visnu then comforted the powerful Garuda, the son of Vinatâ
>   and made him calm and quiet. Wanting to kill Andhaka, Janârdana became
>   infuriated, and, drawing his bow made of horn, call S'ârnga, shot at
>   him arrows after arrows. The Dânava cut off all those arrows to pieces
>   with his own mass of arrows. Then, becoming very angry, he shot fifty
>   sharp arrows at Hari. **Vâsudeva quickly made all those arrows useless
>   and hurled Sudars'ana Chakra with thousand spokes on the Dânava with
>   great violence.**
>   **Andhaka thwarted this with his own discus and shouted aloud with such a great force that all the Devas became confused and
>   confounded**. Visnu's Chakra being baffled, the Devas became
>   distressed with grief and the Dânavas got elated.
>
> **DB 5.6**

Vritrasura, the enemy of Indra, also possessed a Chakra, which was fashioned for him by the Deva Shilpi Viswakarma. It was like the Sudrashana Chakra.

> 43-53. O King! Hearing thus the sweet words of his son, Vis'vakarmâ
>   gladly told his mountain-like son “O my Son! You are capable to save
>   me from troubles (Vrijina) hence you are named Vritra. O highly
>   Fortunate One! Your brother, named Tris'irâ, was a great ascetic; his
>   three faces were all very strong. He was thoroughly conversant with
>   the Vedas and the Vedangâs and well versed in all the other
>   knowledges. He remained always engaged in practising asceticism,
>   surprising to the three worlds. Indra killed my qualified son with his
>   thunderbolt; that wicked soul severed the three heads without any
>   offence. Therefore, O Best of beings! Kill that vicious, shameless,
>   deceitful, wicked Indra guilty of the sin of Brahmahattyâ.” O King!
>   Thus saying, Vis'vakarmâ very much confounded with the breavement of
>   his son, created various divine weapons. **He prepared weapons
>   specially suited to kill Indra, the best axes, tridents, clubs,
>   S'aktis, Tomaras and bows made of horns and arrows, Parighas,
>   Pattis'as, divine discus like the Sudars'an Chakra,** divine
>   inexhaustible arrow cases with arrows, nice Kavacha, very substantial
>   air-like swift-going chariot looking like a cloud and capable to carry
>   great loads; all these he created and gave over to his son.
>
> **DB 6.2**

There can be more references too. Will search for them.

Comment: What is the conclusion here? Sudarshana chakra is a generic weapon or not?

Comment: The question in the title is this " Did anyone besides Vishnu or Krishna use **a Chakra** as a weapon?" The answer to it is Yes. The question in the body is about any Chakra-like weapon viz-  "Is **Chakra a generic weapon** used by others besides Vishnu ?"  The answer again is Yes. Both the questions are about "a Chakra" and not about the "Sudarshana Chakra". @Sarvabhouma

Answer (score 3):

***Disclaimer:*** I'm aware that the OP dislikes Gaudiya Vaishnavism and Chaitanya Mahaprabhu. However, I'm still writing this answer for the sake of others. So my humble request to the OP is not to make an unwanted remarks against Mahaprabhu in response to this answer.

In Chapter 6 of the Madhya Khanda of the Chaitanya Mangalam, Sri Gouranga is said to have wielded the Sudarshan Chakra in retaliation to the two sinful brothers Jagai & Madhais' hitting Nityananda Prabhu's head with a piece of earthen pot:

> Blatantly ignoring their order, Nimai increased the intensity of the kirtana, extended His arms above His head and saturated the sky with the loud chanting of, "Hari! Hari! Hari!"     Their tolerance gone, the sinful brothers stormed out of their house in a mad frenzy. With eyes and faces reddened in anger and minds flaming in rage, they screamed at Gauranga, "You brahmana! Aren't You afraid of anything?" They cursed the Lord with dirty words. Seeing the vicious fury of the demoniac duo frightened the residents of Nadia.     Unaffected, Prabhu Visvambhara Raya, Nityananda, Advaita Acarya, Haridasa, Srivasa, Murari and Mukunda continued the kirtana without stopping. Jagai and Madhai, who were steeped in ignorance, became enraged, grabbed a club and charged at the kirtana party.     They struck Nityananda Prabhu on the head with a piece of earthen pot. Seeing the Lord bleeding profusely, the devotees cried, "Alas! alas!" Sri Gaurahari, feeling sorry within, said, "You two are the vilest of men, and your sins have covered the earth. Now look what you wretched fellows have done." Lord Gauranga, fully aware that calamity 'would assail the earth if Nitai's blood were to touch the ground, dressed Nityananda's wound with His own cloth.     Then **Lord Gaurahari summoned His sudarsana cakra. The personified sudarsana stood before the Lord with folded hands and said, "My Lord, why have You called me?" Sacinandana said, "Sudarsana, because they have hurt Me by hitting Nityananda, you should kill Jagai and Madhai."     Instantly, the sudarsana cakra sped toward Jagai and Madhai who were shaking in fear.**